# Verify my answer is correct: find probability of exactly $k$ HH, given # heads for each of the two coins $\geq m$?

Tags: probability

Toss two fair coins in parallel for $T$ times. Consider the two possible outcomes {HH, not HH} where HH means both coins land heads. Clearly, this is experiment is $\operatorname{Binomial}(n=T,p=1/4)$.

**Question**

Find the probability of having exactly $k$ HH outcomes, given the number of heads in each coin is at least $m$?

**My Answer**

I have worked out this problem, but I'm not sure if my solution is correct. Please let me know what is wrong, if any. Here is how I solved it:

Assume

- $h_1$ number of heads in the 1st coin after $T$ trails
- $h_2$ number of heads in the 2nd coin after $T$ trails
- $h_3$ number of HH for both coins after $T$ trails

So, we would like to calculate:

$$\begin{align*}
P(h_3 = k \mid h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m) &= \frac{P(h_3 = k \text{ AND } h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m)}{P(h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m)} \\
\end{align*}
$$

The denominator: the two events are independent, therefore, the result here is just the product of the probability of each event separately.

The numerator is a little trickier: what is the implication of $h_3=k$ on $h_1$ and $h_2$? And this is exactly the part where I kind of doubt the correctness of my answer.

My best guess is that $h_3=k$ means that $h_1 \geq k$ and $h_2 \geq k$. Why greater or equal? Because we might also have HT and TH outcomes which contribute to $h_1$ and $h_2$ , though these outcomes don't contribute to $h_3$ at all.

As a conclusion, if we combine these four inequalities, we get

$$\begin{align*}
P(h_3 = k \mid h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m) &= \frac{P(h_3 = k \text{ AND } h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m)}{P(h_1 \geq m \text{ AND } h_2 \geq m)} \\
& = \frac{P(h_1 \geq \operatorname{max}\{m,k\} \text{ AND } h_2 \geq \operatorname{max}\{m,k\})}{P(h_1 \geq m)P(h_2 \geq m)} \\
&= \frac{P(h_1 \geq \operatorname{max}\{m,k\}) P(h_2 \geq \operatorname{max}\{m,k\})}{P(h_1 \geq m)P(h_2 \geq m)}
\end{align*}
$$

If my answer is correct, then we can conclude that if $m \geq k$ then this probability is exactly 1, and this is what makes me suspicious about my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your logic comes from when you said $P(h_3=k\text{ and }h_1\ge m\text{ and }h_2\ge m)=P(h_1\ge \max(m,k)\text{ and } h_2\ge \max(m,k))$. That last statement is only true with a $\le$ instead of $=$. Just because $h_1,h_2$ are at least as big as $m$ and $k$ does not imply $h_3=k$, because the instances of each head might not match up.

Suppose you are given that $h_1=m_1$, $h_2=m_2$. In this case, the number of ways to have exactly $k$ instances of HH would be
$$
\binom{T}k\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}
$$
because there are $\binom{T}k$ choices for which times both coins are heads, $\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}$ for which of the remaining times the first coin is heads and the second is tails, and $\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}$ for which times the first is tails and the second is heads.

This shows that
$$
P(h_3=k\text{ and }h_1=m_1\text{ and }h_2=m_2)=\frac1{2^{2T}}\binom{T}k\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}
$$ 
so
$$
P(h_3=k\text{ and } h_1\ge m\text{ and }h_2\ge m)=\frac1{2^{2T}}\sum_{m_1,m_2\ge m}\binom{T}k\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}
$$
Dividing the last number by
$$
P(h_1\ge m\text{ and }h_2\ge m)=\left(\frac{1}{2^T}\sum_{i=m}^T\binom{T}{i}\right)^2
$$
gives the desired conditional probability.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: I guess you meant $$
P(h_3=k\text{ and }h_1=m_1\text{ and }h_2=m_2)=\binom{T}{k} \frac1{2^{2T}} \binom{T-k}{m_1-k} \frac1{2^{m_1-k}} \binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k} \frac1{2^{m_2-k}}
$$ instead of $$
P(h_3=k\text{ and }h_1=m_1\text{ and }h_2=m_2)=\frac1{2^{2T}}\binom{T}k\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}
$$ 
, right?

Comment: No, I meant what I said. $\binom{T}k\binom{T-k}{m_1-k}\binom{T-m_1}{m_2-k}$ is the number of series of coin flips for which $h_3=k$, $h_1=m_1$, $h_2=m_2$, and each of these series has a probability of $\frac1{2^{2T}}$ of occurring, so multiplying these two gives the total probability.